# how to show past 20 days in this SQL Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I want to change the criteria at the end. to the past 20 days. 
is this ? (DateTime.Now.Year ) - 20 ?

```
  sqlT1 = "SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID_KEY DESC) AS RN,* From(Select distinct f.FACILITY_NAME, ID_KEY, [BATCH] AS column1, [IMPORTDATE], [DATEBILLED], [RX], [DATEDISPENSED], [DAYSUPPLY], [PAYTYPE], [NPI], [PHYSICIAN], [COST], [QUANTITY], [MEDICATION], A.[NDC], " +
                        " case when (COST > 0 AND DAYSUPPLY > 0) then (COST / DAYSUPPLY) * 30 else 0 end [30DayCost] , [PATIENTNAME], [ROUTEOFADMIN], [INVOICECAT], [COPAY], [BRAND], [TIER], [SKILLLEVEL], [STAT] STATUS, [LASTTASKDATE],SEQNO, 'please bring to the attention of the administrator.' SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS  , f.FACILITY_ID " +
                        " FROM [LMI].[T_CHARGES] A Left Outer Join PBM.FACILITY f on A.FACILITYNPI = f.FACILITY_NPI  " +
                        " Where COST > 500 " +
                        " AND [TIER] = 'T1' and month(A.DATEDISPENSED) = " + DateTime.Now.Month + " and year(A.DATEDISPENSED) = " + DateTime.Now.Year + "" +
                        sqlWhere + " AND f.FACILITY_ID IN (" + selected + ")";
```

Comment: This looks like it will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You do know what those are right?

Comment: SQL injections have nothing whatsoever in common with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the date 20 days ago, you can use the sql function DATEADD:

```
WHERE A.DATEDISPENSED >= DATEADD(dd,-20,GetDate())
```

Answer (score 1):

well I don't know about changing your code for you but generally in SQL you use `getdate()` to get today's date and you use `dateadd(d,-20,getdate())` to get 20 days ago so use

(t-sql):

```
 testingdate between dateadd(d,-20,getdate()) and getdate()
```

in your where clause

Comment: [dateadd link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)  and  [getdate()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx)